What is the best way to save and load a Qiskit backend?
I'm performing some quantum experiments with Qiskit and I want to use a simulator that mimics a real quantum computer with recent calibration results, like so:
from qiskit_ibm_runtime import QiskitRuntimeService
from qiskit_aer import AerSimulator
service = QiskitRuntimeService(channel="ibm_quantum", token="MY_TOKEN")
backend = service.backend("ibm_brisbane")
simulator = AerSimulator.from_backend(backend)

My problem is that I want my experiments to be reproducible in the future, and I believe that the above code snippet pulls the latest calibration results that are updated every 24 hours. Therefore, I wanted to somehow save the backend object to disk (which I would include in my publicly available replication package) and have my script load it instead of pulling it from the IBM Quantum service. Initially, I tried using the pickle module, but the backend object contains many attributes that don't seem relevant and some that should not be made publicly available (such as my token).
I am aware of qiskit_ibm_runtime.fake_provider, but the system snapshots here are too old.
To summarize my question: what is the best way to persist and reuse a Qiskit backend object?

When you access backend properties using IBMBackend.properties method you can specify a datetime to get an instance of the BackendProperties whose timestamp is closest to, but older than, the specified datetime. Then use this instance to create the simulator.
The following code shows how to do that:
from qiskit.providers.models import BackendProperties
from qiskit_aer import AerSimulator
from qiskit_aer.backends.backendconfiguration import AerBackendConfiguration
from qiskit_aer.noise import NoiseModel
from qiskit_ibm_runtime import IBMBackend
import datetime as dt

def simulator_from_backend(backend: IBMBackend, datetime: dt.datetime, **options):
    configuration = AerBackendConfiguration(
        backend_name=f"aer_simulator_from({backend.name})",
        backend_version=backend.backend_version,
        n_qubits=backend.num_qubits,
        basis_gates=backend.operation_names,
        gates=[],
        max_shots=int(1e6),
        coupling_map=list(backend.coupling_map.get_edges()),
        max_experiments=backend.max_circuits,
        description=f"{backend.name} in {datetime}",
    )

    properties = BackendProperties.from_dict(backend.properties(datetime=datetime).to_dict())
    target = backend.target_history(datetime=datetime)

    options["noise_model"] = NoiseModel.from_backend_properties(properties)

    return AerSimulator(configuration=configuration, properties=properties, target=target, **options)

And you can use the function simulator_from_backend as follows:
service = QiskitRuntimeService()
backend = service.backend('ibm_sherbrooke')

datetime = dt.datetime(2024, 8, 1)
simulator = simulator_from_backend(backend, datetime)

The issue with this method is that if the backend used in your experiments is retired you will not be able to access its historical data.
Another option is to obtain backend calibration data by downloading it in CSV format from the backend page and save it for future use. The procedure outlined in this blog post can be used to load it.
